# Masking in Matlab

Tags: matlab, masking

I have encountered with a problem which might be super easy but I am spending some times on it. I will appreciate any help.

I have a matrix R (1024x1280 double) which the indexes are 0 and 1 and another matrix of F (3000x2 double), which are the location of 3000 points(of course in terms of R matrix). How could I choose the points in F matrix which that locations are 1 in the R matrix. 
I have tried following way but still does not give me the right answer:

```
siz= size(R);
fet = false(siz(1),siz(2));
fet(F(:,1),F(:,2)) = true;
[xf,yf]=find(fet==1 & R==1);`
```

I know that I could write a for loop in F and choose one by one point `(F(1,1)`,`F(1,2))` and check if the same point in the R matrix is equal to 1 and then save the point. But this is non efficient way. Can anybody give me a hand in this regards? 
Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub2ind` to convert `F` to linear indices and then index into `R` to get the booleans.

```
bool = logical(R(sub2ind(size(R), F(:,1), F(:,2))));
touse = F(bool,:);
```

Comment: Thanks. And how to get the right points of F from booleans. I am a beginner in matlab. sorry for stupid question.

Comment: @Sam Updated with an example.

Comment: Thanks. It gave me this error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. and then I have changed it to this form.tout=F(logical(bool),:); and working properly. Thanks a lot.